# VB manipulate lots of labels inside panel

Tags: vb.net, panel, label

So i have like 100 labels inside a panel and i need to to change their texts.I Tried an for and i tried Tab Index like an array without success, any ideas how I can select and change properties of these labels?

```
Sub setCartela(ByVal numeros As Integer)
    For cont As Integer = 0 To numeros Step 1
//change labels text inside panel
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this ...

```
Dim i as Integer = 1
For Each ctrl As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If ctrl.GetType.ToString = "System.Windows.Forms.Label" Then
            ctrl.Text = "Text" & format(i)
        End If
        i += 1
Next
```

Comment: There is a small bug in your code. You have to convert `Panel1` into `Panel1.Controls`. Other than that it is OK; although perhaps it would look better `If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
dim _countLbl as integer = 1 
For each Lbl as Label in Panel1.Controls.Oftype(Of Label)()

Lbl.text="Label" & _countLbl    
_countLbl += 1

Next
```